# VBA Runtime Error when adding Data Validation

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am trying to update the data validation lists on multiple worksheets with a macro. Below you can find the codes.
Unfortunately, I am getting an "application defined or object defined" error at the ".Add Type:=xlVali...." row.

Can you people help me, why I'm getting that error.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next

Dim Xws As Worksheet
For Each Xws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Xws.Name = "Acilis" Or Xws.Name = "Admin_Sayfasi" Or Xws.Name = "Sheet4" Or Xws.Name = "Sheet2" Or Xws.Name = "Giris" Or Xws.Name = "Kunye" Or Xws.Name = "Kilavuz" Or Xws.Name = "Yonetim" Or Xws.Name = "SheetX" Or Xws.Name = "Butonlar" Or Xws.Name = "Sheet3" Or Xws.Name = "Ders_TEMP" Or Xws.Name = "Egitim Bilgileri" Or Xws.Name = "Mudurluk_TEMP" Or Xws.Name = "Egitmen_TEMP" Or Xws.Name = "Egitmen_List" Or Xws.Name = "Baskanlik_TEMP" Or Xws.Name = "Ekip_Uye_List" Or Xws.Name = "Deneme2" Or Xws.Name = "Uretim_TEMP" Or Xws.Name = "Personel_TEMP" Or Xws.Name = "Bilgiler" Or Xws.Name = "Sheet1" Or Xws.Name = "Puanlama" Or Xws.Name = "Deneme" Or Xws.Name = "Admin" Then

GoTo Next1
Else

XwsQ = Xws.Name

Worksheets(XwsQ).Select
Worksheets(XwsQ).Range("P22:P1111").Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Ekip_Uye_List!$A$1:$A$" & LastRowB & ""
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With


Next1:

Next

Dim Xws2 As Worksheet
For Each Xws2 In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Xws2.Name <> "Acilis" Then
        Xws2.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The codes are long, and it goes like this. But I cannot clear that error.

> Sorry to say this but it was my own fault. I found that I've made an error while declaring the LastRowB unfortunately. The error was caused because of that. The first codes I've pasted here works great. Problem was on LastRowB at the row which gave the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add a & over here

> = & "=Ekip_Uye_List!$A$1:$A$" &

```
Dim sh As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next

Dim Xws As Worksheet
For Each Xws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Xws.Name = "Acilis" Or Xws.Name = "Admin_Sayfasi" Or Xws.Name = "Sheet4" Or Xws.Name = "Sheet2" Or Xws.Name = "Giris" Or Xws.Name = "Kunye" Or Xws.Name = "Kilavuz" Or Xws.Name = "Yonetim" Or Xws.Name = "SheetX" Or Xws.Name = "Butonlar" Or Xws.Name = "Sheet3" Or Xws.Name = "Ders_TEMP" Or Xws.Name = "Egitim Bilgileri" Or Xws.Name = "Mudurluk_TEMP" Or Xws.Name = "Egitmen_TEMP" Or Xws.Name = "Egitmen_List" Or Xws.Name = "Baskanlik_TEMP" Or Xws.Name = "Ekip_Uye_List" Or Xws.Name = "Deneme2" Or Xws.Name = "Uretim_TEMP" Or Xws.Name = "Personel_TEMP" Or Xws.Name = "Bilgiler" Or Xws.Name = "Sheet1" Or Xws.Name = "Puanlama" Or Xws.Name = "Deneme" Or Xws.Name = "Admin" Then

GoTo Next1
Else

XwsQ = Xws.Name

Worksheets(XwsQ).Select
Worksheets(XwsQ).Range("P22:P1111").Select
With Selection.Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
xlBetween, Formula1:= & "=Ekip_Uye_List!$A$1:$A$" & LastRowB & ""
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.InputTitle = ""
.ErrorTitle = ""
.InputMessage = ""
.ErrorMessage = ""
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: But now this row gives me "expected expression" error. :S

Comment: Try this: `Formula1:= &  chr(34) & "=Ekip_Uye_List!$A$1:$A$" & LastRowB & chr(34)`

Comment: Still the same.. But now it gives the expression error for the first &, right before " chr(34) "

Answer (score 0):

can you please format your code example so it can be complied corretlly (Alt+D)

1. "If" is not closed
2. "Next XWS" is missing
3. XwsQ is not declared

It would be easier to help you if you present you problem in "working" way .

Comment: I've added the last part of the codes. In the middle, there is 2 other parts to add data validation. But because of the error on the first row, I cannot even move to the rest of the codes. It's not a "Next" or something like that.